# App starts failed then log the current user out?

Tags: 18.04

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 for 2 days. I also installed some apps on it via Software Center (include Atom and Skype)

Everytime I open these apps, the system logs me out that I can not open these app even once. I understand that Ubuntu 18.04 is the lastest release so it can contain bugs. Is my problem one of its bugs? What should I do?

Comment: are the apps you installed snaps by any chance? type `snap list` in the terminal and check the output.

Comment: Thank you. I have reinstalled all of them by deb package from their official sites. The problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im also new to linux and I had a similar problem, i boot up spotify and it just stays black screen.
What worked for me is to go to console and type

`program_name --disable-gpu`

I'm not sure if that is going to fix your problem, but you can still try.
Hope this works out :)

Comment: It worked. But I don't want to open Terminal to type the command whenever I want to open the program, so I have reinstalled them by deb package from their official sites.Thank you!